# Get MongoDB Atlas to release space of deleted documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have an Atlas cluster running a 3 node replica set and I'm getting alerts that the disk utilisation has exceeded 90%. Despite deleting a ton of documents the alerts persist because MongoDB doesn't release the cleared space to the OS - it reserves it for future use. But MongoDB continues to alert. I don't want to change the alerting in case I get a real issue.

Can anyone advise of the standard approach to solving this?

Comment: Are there any issues with https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/compact/ ?

Comment: It doesn't say how to connect to a secondary directly. Turns out that when connecting to a node directly you have to add "--tls --authenticationDatabase admin" to the connection string. This was. missing in the Atlas web console